# Regex match more criteria

Tags: regex

In java, I want to keep in the test string only the letters, but I also want to remove the word Poppins from it. 
I currently have :

```
String test = "01 - Poppins - Poppins - Asurrect";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("[^(A-Za-z\\s)]", "").trim());
```

this gives me : 
Poppins Poppins Asurrect

but I want just Asurrect.

I would prefer just to concatenate this to my current regex, without anything fancy, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex alternation if you just want to do it with pure regex:

```
String test = "01 - Poppins - Poppins - Asurrect";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\bPoppins\\b|[^A-Za-z\\s]+", "").trim());
//=> Asurrect
```

- `\b` is for word boundary.
- There is no need to use `(...)` inside character class as you've shown in question
- Better to use quantifier to minimize replacements.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ8wQ9/2)